# Server Error: Invalid plot index and many duplicate plots

Tags: r, plot

I am not sure why, but it seems as if my code is plotting LOTS of plots in RStudio. I am new to R and RStudio so I can't figure out how many is being plotted, but I think there are duplicates, previous plots, and the plots I want, all within the `Plots` tab in RStudio. Also, when I try to scroll to see which plots are created, I am getting popups

[image]

I am expecting 5 plots for each state but it seems as though I am getting a lot more

```
library(ggplot2)
try(data('midwest', package='ggplot2'))
for (s in unique(midwest$state)) {
  state_data = subset(midwest, state == s)
  print(
    ggplot(state_data, aes(x=county, y=percprof)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    labs(title=paste(s)) + 
    xlab('Counties') + ylab('Percentage') + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
  )
}
```

Comment: when I run your code I get 5 plots , 1 per state, as I would expect. You can try to clear all plots and then run your code again.

Comment: The above code works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine for me. Try restarting R. It may be a server issue, but it's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, run dev.off(), just to be safe.

Comment: Where do I run `dev.off()` ? Also what does it do in layman terms?

Comment: Sometimes you end up with open plot devices, and running dev.off() allows you to begin plotting again with a clean slate, basically.

Comment: And just type dev.off() in the terminal